# How can I list the functions that were made available via a #include in C?

Tags: c

what is the substitute for something like this,

```
dir(int)
```

in C?
when I include something like,

```
#include <string.h>
```

then I would like to see what is being included.

Comment: no specific IDE, using ‘%%shell’ to run c in google colab, but I use PyCharm apart from google colab

Comment: When you run `#include <string.h>`, there exists a literal file on your hard drive called `string.h` that's being included. You can open that file in your text editor and read it.

Comment: Another thing you can do is tell your compiler to run the preprocessor only, so it replaces `#include <string.h>` with the content of the `string.h` file, and you can read the output from that preprocessor run and see all the functions that are available for your use.

Comment: Another important note: the contents of things like `string.h` are provided by your libc, not your compiler, so it's not the source code to (say) gcc that you'd care about at all here; instead, it the source to glibc (or whatever other libc is in use in the environment you're compiling against -- Microsoft has their own, Linux has alternatives, traditional BSD operating systems have their own libc as part of the operating system's codebase, etc). But all of them follow what the standard tells them they need to do, so what you should be doing is learning the standard, not the implementation.

Comment: You read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

Answer (score 1):

C does not have any introspective feature analogous to Python's `dir()`.  It also does not have an object model at all like Python's, which would be necessary to make that sensible.  Especially, it does not have anything along the lines of packages- or modules-as-objects, which is the only way that an analogue of `dir()` could be useful for inspecting header contents.

The C programmer generally approaches the issue from exactly the opposite direction: (1) what functions do I need? (2) what headers provide their declarations, and what additional libraries, if any, need to be linked to get their implementations?

Comment: is there a github repository for the official c language, just like for python, there is cpython repository?

Comment: Just wanted to add that the reason C does not have this functionality is because there is no need for it. If you know the type of a variable you can determine all of the fields at compile time by viewing where the type is declared. Other than that, there is nothing else in memory to give it any hints at runtime except what you explicitly tell it to store in memory.

Comment: @apostofes, there doesn't exist a single official C implementation in the first place. C is a _specification_, not an implementation. So there's no equivalent to the cpython repo for C, as you can't have a github repo for something that doesn't exist. :)

Comment: @apostofes There is no single implementation of C like there is in python. However, C does have a 571 page PDF describing every aspect of how the language should function regardless of the compiler you choose. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2346.pdf Happy Reading.

Comment: No, @apostofes, there is no C reference implementation such as Python has.  There is an international specification for the C language, managed by the ISO, and a rather large number of implementations by various providers.  Many are closed source, but you can examine GCC's source if you want.  Or you would probably be more interested in GLibc, the GNU implementation of the C standard library.  Not that either is at all an easy read.  If you want reference material, then reading the language spec is my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCC to compile your code you can use:

```
gcc -E NAMEOFFILE.c
```

Which will give you the file after its run through the preprocessor.